# Django: How to create a new model with a foreign key associated to a previously visited model

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I'm currently working on a web app, and I'm using config files to upload the names for certain models.

How would I go about associating these created models to a `ForeignKey` associated to a parent model class that already exists in a different app?

For example, I have the following models:

```
# Base models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

# Child models.py
class child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.foreignKey('Parent', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

The first base models will already exist within the database and will be used in a previous view. Then in the current views I'll call a function that will get or create a certain amount of child models, based on the number of rows in the csv file, and pass these generated models into the html template.

What I'm not sure how to do is making sure that the models created in the function will have the appropriate foreign key that associates it to the right specific model used in the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know beforehand which model the `ForeignKey` will point to, you can use djangos [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

The gist of it is like follows (example from the docs):

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you are intending to do, but this could be a step in the right direction.